# Is the html version of the Master page the only way to change it?

Tags: 2013, master-page

My employers want a link in the NavBar changed and this link is part of the Master page.  However even though the Master page is set as XXXX, there is no HTML version of this file anywhere.  There is only a xxx.Master file.  My understanding of SharePoint 2013 is you must have the .html and the .master versions of a master file to make a change to it.  I didn't think this was even possible!  Oh and it's working fine with only the .Master verion.

Answer (score 1):

You can still modify the .master file as you could in past versions, although the preferred way is through the .html file. Tools such as SharePoint Designer still support that, but beware of unghosting/customizing the file because it'll lose synchronization with the .master file in the 15 hive.